# Truncation of InnerText at Whiteshpace

Tags: innertext

I am creating a text box for editing within a table. However, if there is whitespace in the value of the table cell, it appears in the textbox as only characters up to the first whitespace encountered. From debugging, cellsContent[i].innerText has the correct value, but editableTaskCells[i].firstChild.value does not.

```
 function editTask(row) {
        // make array of current contents of cells
        var cellsContent = 
        document.getElementById("taskTable").rows[row].cells;
        // delete row
        document.getElementById("taskTable").deleteRow(row);
        // make new row
        var newRow = document.getElementById("taskTable").insertRow(row);
        // make an array for editable cells of new row
        var editableTaskCells = [];
        // fill contents of new row with editable contents of deleted row
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            editableTaskCells[i] = newRow.insertCell(i);
            if (i < 5) {
                editableTaskCells[i].innerHTML = "<input type='text' 
                           size='10' value= " + cellsContent[i].innerText + "></input>";
              documnet.writeln(cellsContent[i].innerText;
              document.writeln(editableTaskCells[i].firstChild.value); // for debugging purposes
            }
        }

        // add edit and remove buttons
        editableTaskCells[5].innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='editButton' value='Save Edit' onclick='saveEditedTask(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";
        editableTaskCells[6].innerHTML = "<input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='removeButton' value='REMOVE' onclick='removeTask(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)' />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Forgot quotes around the value in the input statement. Stupid mistake. It should be

```
editableTaskCells[i].innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="10" value= "' +  
cellsContent[i].innerText + '"></input>';
```